# Cannot invoke 'SKSpriteNode.init' with an argument list of type '(texture: SKTexture, color: UIColor, size: CGSize, () -> ())'

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Can anyone help me solve this issue? The error shown is being generated even though I am using the designated initializer.

```
class OtherOrb: SKSpriteNode {

override init() {

    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Orb")

    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clear, size: texture.size()){
        self.position = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 500.0)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20) 
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because of the closure you have trailing your initialiser.

In Swift, the compiler interprets a closure directly after a method call as the final argument to said method call, and hence the error you are getting effectively says that no initialiser that includes that closure argument exists.

Furthermore, your code looks very off, and I'm not convinced it's valid Swift. What are you trying to accomplish?

Based on my suspicions, I believe your code should resemble the following:

```
class OtherOrb: SKSpriteNode {

    init() {

        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Orb")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clear, size: texture.size())

        self.position = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 500.0)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

That is to say that you want an initialiser with no args to be your designated initialiser.

Comment: Thank you, Jacob. Could you explain the "@available" parts? I've never seen anything like that in any examples or questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sure, so by marking the method as unavailable, the compiler will complain if you try and use it. Furthermore, it won't be indexed by Xcode auto complete so it just makes the development experience a little nicer. It is totally optional though, not necessary, just my personal preference. :)

Comment: Not a good idea to make the required init unavailable, "required" exists for a reason lol

Comment: Under most circumstances I would agree, though take the context of this particular scenario. Should the initialiser be invoked, the application will terminate. The coder init is generally invoked by either IB, or NSKeyedArchiver. Given that neither of them are used here, it is quite safe to make the method unavailable.